# Приложение не устанавливается во второй раз

Tags: android, apk

Я подписываю `APK`, выбираю тип `Debug`, распространяю так, напрямую, в `Play Google` не буду выкладывать. Устанавливаю и норм.

Но проблема в том,  что я обратно ставлю этот же `APK`, не установлено пишет.

1) Попробовал удалить, удалить для всех пользователей и заново, все тщетно. Помогает одно, `version code` поднимаю на 2, `version name` на 1.1, подписываю и обратно откатываю эти данные и подписываю заново. Только тогда устанавливается. 
Потом опять, установить этот же `APK` не получается.

2) Отключил в Google Play "Проверять угрозы безопасности", и отлично работает

3) Еще если залить на Google Play в закрытом тестировании и оттуда скачать APK и установить, проблема исчезает, даже без удаления старого, поверх устанавливается.

Возможно кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим, подскажите?

Comment: а почему вы не пользуетесь встроенны дебагом? Подключите устройство к компьютеру и обкатывайте напряму, без создания apk-шек. И да, что он пишет если попытаться установить? Какая ошибка?

Comment: "Помогает одно, version code поднимаю на 2" - это ожидаемое правильное поведение. Приложение устанавливается из апк только если код версии выше, чем у уже установленной версии. "version name" можно не менять.

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев, Обновил вопрос. Для распространения нужно подписывать. А ошибка просто "Приложение не установлено" и все

Comment: @Эникейщик, да, я в курсе, но как раз из-за этого я удаляю полностью с телефона и заново устанавливаю

Comment: у меня несколько раз были проблемы с установкой apk, но удаления приложения полностью, ото всех пользователей - исправляло проблему. Есть ли ваше приложение в списке всех приложений?

Comment: Да, я об этом написал в первой попытке. Удаляю везде.

Comment: Напишите модель телефона точно и тайна раскроется. Некоторые производители имеют свои установочные агенты поверх нативного лаунчера, и когда вы вроде удалили приложение и его нигде нет, оно попадает туда(типо корзины), вам надо знать это, зайти и удалить

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, это и на Xiaomi и на Samsung происходит. Еще если залить на Google Play в закрытом тестировании и оттуда скачать APK и установить, проблема исчезает, даже без удаления старого поверх устанавливается. Вопрос обновлю...